# Delphi - ListView onItemClick is not being fired

Tags: android, ios, listview, delphi, firemonkey

I'm working with a `ListView` component for both `Android` and `iOS`.

The `onClick` event is fired when the user hits the list, however the `onItemClick` event never occurs (yes, I did test them separately).

I'm also generating the `ListItems` dynamically, in the simplest way:

```
listview_available_gen.Items.Add.Text := 'whythehellyoudontitemclick';
```

Am I missing something silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why `onItemClick` is not being fired, but I replaced it with `onItemClickEx` and now it's receiving the event just fine.

Source: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.OnItemClickEx

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `onItemClick` event on `ListView` is really pointing to the same procedure as in your code. Double click the `OnItemClick` in `ListView` `Events` page and it will move you to the procedure which it created or if there is none it will create new one.